# Apache Spark 2.0 library preference

Tags: java, maven, elasticsearch, apache-spark, classpath

**In short:** In Spark 2.0 `spark-submit` prefers his version of Guava library (14.0.1) - but I want to use recent jar version (19.0).

**Question:** How convince Spark to use version provided in my `pom.xml` file?

**My suspicion:** I can use `spark.driver.userClassPathFirst=true` option. But it is **experimental** feature ([Spark 2.0.0 doc](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/configuration.html#runtime-environment)) - so maybe there is better solution?

---

**Problem detailed explanation:**

I'm using Spark 2.0.0 (hadoop2.7) and Elasticsearch 2.3.4. And I'm fighting with very simple application which tries use Spark Streaming and Elasticsearch together. Here it is:

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SampleApp");
JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.milliseconds(500));
jssc.checkpoint("/tmp");
JavaDStream<String> messages = jssc.textFileStream("/some_directory_path");

TransportClient client = TransportClient.builder().build()
    .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));

messages.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
    XContentBuilder builder = jsonBuilder()
            .startObject()
            .field("words", "some words")
            .endObject();

    clientTu.prepareIndex("indexName", "typeName")
        .setSource(builder.string())
        .get();
});

jssc.start();
jssc.awaitTermination();
```

The project is build with Maven. Here is part of pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
                <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>19.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <createSourcesJar>true</createSourcesJar>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>com.abc.App</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

As you can see I've done some exclusions. 
And everything seems great, but after execution using command:

```
spark-submit --class com.abc.App --master local[2]  /somePath/superApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I gain the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
    at org.elasticsearch.threadpool.ThreadPool.<clinit>(ThreadPool.java:190)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient$Builder.build(TransportClient.java:131)
    at com.abc.App.main(App.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:729)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

After adding `--conf spark.driver.userClassPathFirst=true` to `spark-submit` command, the application seems to work correctly. But I'm not sure this is the right way to manage this problem, because this option is marked in documentation as *experimental*.

In other words, Spark prefers libraries from his runtime environment and ignores those provided in "uber" jar (assembled jar). So I want to know how change this behavior in proper way?

**Question again:** What I have to do to be sure that particular jar defined in my POM will be used in runtime (with defined version)?

---

**Edit:** In more complex application which tries to use both Spark Streaming and Elasticsearch there're the same problems with other libraries (for example `io.netty:netty`). And in such situation, simple `spark.driver.userClassPathFirst` option activation doesn't help at all.

Comment: Can you check to see which guava pom was actually included in your jar? `jar xf` will list its contents. Also, it seem that it is elastic search and _not_ spark that cannot find guava on the classpath. Guava needs to be available on the classpath or bundled in the jar file.

Comment: @Phil Thanks for comment. In the jar there is `/META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.properties` file where is info: `version=19.0`. So version in jar is correct. There is runtime problem - it looks like `spark-submit` ignores guava19 and takes his older version from local jar repository located in `./spark_2.0/jars/`. Any idea how to configure Spark to fix that?

Comment: If `./spark_2.0/jars/` is a local directory, perhaps removing the jar from that directory will work. Alternatively, you can add an exclude directive to your maven configuration to prevent the older guava dependency from getting pulled in.